# Deleting a node from a binary search tree without recursion

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

I have a binary search tree. I want to delete a node from it:

```
void deleteANode(struct node *head, int value) {
    //let us find the node
    struct node *temp = head;
    struct node *parent = NULL;

    //let us find the node
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (value > temp->data) {
            parent = temp;
            temp = temp->right;
        } else
        if (value < temp->data) {
            parent = temp;
            temp = temp->left;
        } else {
            //let us check for child nodes
            //
            if (temp->left == NULL && temp->right == NULL) {
                printf("Deleting a leaf.\n");

                temp = NULL;
                printf("Set temp null.\n");
                free(temp);
                break;
            } else
            if (temp->left == NULL || temp->right == NULL) {
                printf("Deleting a one child.\n");
                //one of the child is null
                if (temp->left != NULL) {
                    parent->left = temp->left;
                } else {
                    parent->right = temp->right;
                }
                free(temp);
            } else {
                printf("Deleting two child parent.\n");
                //both of them are not NULL
                //need to find the pre-order successor
                struct node *temp2 = temp->right;

                while (temp2->left != NULL) {
                    temp2 = temp2->left;
                }
                //found the successor.
                temp->data = temp2->data;
                free(temp);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to delete a leaf node in this block:

```
if (temp->left == NULL && temp->right == NULL) {
    printf("Deleting a leaf.\n");

    temp->data = NULL;
    printf("Set temp null.\n");
    free(temp);
    break;
}
```

But the above code doesn't work.

I am calling the above method:

```
deleteANode(head, 3);
```

The preorder traversal is remains same before and after:

> 5 4 3 10 7 20 Deleting a leaf. Set temp null.
>   =============== 5 4 3 10 7 20

What am I doing wrong.

Updated as per @pstrjds comments:

```
if (temp->left == NULL && temp->right == NULL ) {
    printf("Deleting a leaf.\n");
    parent->left = NULL;
    parent->right = NULL;
    free(temp);
    temp = NULL;
    printf("Set temp null.\n");
    break;
}
```

It's working fine for leaf node. Need to work for node with two children.

Comment: Well for one thing, you are setting `temp` to NULL before you call free on it. You should probably free it first (this is in the if block that checks for a leaf)

Comment: `You should probably free it first.`? Should or must? I think free first means it doesn't exist any longer. Although doing the same doesn't solve my issue, rather it gives `0` instead of `3` for deleted key.

Comment: I should be clearer, my apologies, you should call `free(temp)` before you set temp to `null` otherwise you are not freeing the node and are just calling free on null.  You would also want to ensure that the parent node no longer points to it.

Comment: Did the same, but got output: `5
4
3
10
7
20
Deleting a leaf.
Set temp null.
===============
5
4
0
10
7
20`. Okay, do I need another node as parent node to make it work?

Comment: Can you update the question with your updated code - from the new output it would seem to me that you did not fix up the parent for the leaf node, so the parent is pointing to a null node or something of that nature.

Comment: I have pointed parent left and right to NULL as per your answer. It is working fine now.

Comment: Please see my answer, you would not want to point both the left and right to NULL, that is not what I was suggesting, you just want the left or right, whichever was pointing to the leaf, to be null.

Comment: ...but then, if the other parent leaf is already NULL, does that not mean that the parent needs to be deleted too?  (and so on..)

Comment: @MartinJames - I wouldn't think so, the code was deleting a single node containing a single value. The parent node would still contain a value and so should not be deleted. I was just indicating that once the leaf is being deleted then the parent which was pointing at it should no longer point to the deleted node. Apparently my English this evening is faulty and so is leading to confusion. I think the answer I posted makes it clearer. The method name itself is "deleteANode" not deleteMultipleNodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the block of code which is deleting a leaf you are not actually freeing the node nor are you updating the parent node to no longer point to it.

```
if ( temp -> left == NULL && temp -> right == NULL )
{
    printf("Deleting a leaf.\n");
    if (parent->left == temp)
    {
        parent->left = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        parent->right = NULL;
    }

    free(temp);
    temp = NULL;
    printf("Set temp null.\n");
    break;
 }
```

You could actually remove the line `temp = NULL` and change the `break;` to a return statement.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your code works fine. `temp = NULL` is useless here. But what do you mean by `change the break; to a return statement.`? Should I return from this point. I am using all this logic in while loop. I think breaking would do the same.

Comment: @learner - It does accomplish the same thing, but the difference would be in readability. If I see a break statement in code, I have to look where the loop is and then search after the loop to see what else might happen. If I see a return statement I know that the method will complete execution at the return statement.  In my opinion, the return statement will better express the intent and make it obvious that the method is done at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code really work?
It should be like this:

```
printf("Deleting two child parent.\n");
Node* temp2 = temp->right;
while(temp2->left != NULL)
{
    parent = temp2;
    temp2 = temp2->left;
}

temp->data = temp2->data;
parent->left = NULL;
delete temp2;

return;
```

Comment: Correction in my previous response: parent->left = temp2->right;   Before deleting temp2

Answer (score 0):

Java Solution

```
// Java program to demonstrate delete operation in binary search tree 
class BinarySearchTree 
{ 
  /* Class containing left and right child of current node and key value*/
  class Node 
  { 
    int key; 
    Node left, right; 

    public Node(int item) 
    { 
        key = item; 
        left = right = null; 
    } 
} 

// Root of BST 
Node root; 

// Constructor 
BinarySearchTree() 
{ 
    root = null; 
} 

// This method mainly calls deleteRec() 
void deleteKey(int key) 
{ 
    root = deleteRec(root, key); 
} 

/* A recursive function to insert a new key in BST */
Node deleteRec(Node root, int key) 
{  Node x=root;
 Node parent =null;
    /* Base Case: If the tree is empty */
    while(x!=null)
    {
      if(x.key>key)
      { parent=x;
        x=x.left;
      }
      else if(x.key<key)
      {parent=x;
        x=x.right;
      }
      else
      {
        if(x.left==null&&x.right==null)
        {
         System.out.println(x.key+"y1");
          if(parent.left==x)
          parent.left=null;
          else if(parent.right==x)
          parent.right=null;

          x=null;

          break;
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println(x.key+"y2");
          if(x.left==null)
          { 
            if(parent.right==x)
            parent.right=x.right;
            else if(parent.left==x)
             parent.left=x.right;
            System.out.println(x.key+"yes");
            x=null;
            break;
          }
          else if(x.right==null)
          {
            if(parent.left==x)
            parent.left=x.left;
            else if(parent.right==x)
            parent.right=x.left;
            x=null;
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            Node temp=x;
            Node px=null;
            temp=temp.right;
            while(temp.left!=null)
            { px=temp;
              temp=temp.left;
            }
            x.key=temp.key;
            if(px.left==temp)
            px.left=null;
            else if(px.left==temp)
            px.right=null;
            temp=null;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  return root;
} 

int minValue(Node root) 
{ 
    int minv = root.key; 
    while (root.left != null) 
    { 
        minv = root.left.key; 
        root = root.left; 
    } 
    return minv; 
} 

// This method mainly calls insertRec() 
void insert(int key) 
{ 
    root = insertRec(root, key); 
} 

/* A recursive function to insert a new key in BST */
Node insertRec(Node root, int key) 
{ 

    /* If the tree is empty, return a new node */
    if (root == null) 
    { 
        root = new Node(key); 
        return root; 
    } 

    /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    if (key < root.key) 
        root.left = insertRec(root.left, key); 
    else if (key > root.key) 
        root.right = insertRec(root.right, key); 

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return root; 
} 

// This method mainly calls InorderRec() 
void inorder() 
{ 
    inorderRec(root); 
} 

// A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST 
void inorderRec(Node root) 
{ 
    if (root != null) 
    { 
        inorderRec(root.left); 
        System.out.print(root.key + " "); 
        inorderRec(root.right); 
    } 
} 

// Driver Program to test above functions 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(); 

    /* Let us create following BST 
        50 
    /    \ 
    30   70 
    / \ / \ 
    20 40 60 80 */
    tree.insert(50); 
    tree.insert(30); 
    tree.insert(20); 
    tree.insert(40); 
    tree.insert(70); 
    tree.insert(60); 
    tree.insert(80); 

    System.out.println("Inorder traversal of the given tree"); 
    tree.inorder(); 

    System.out.println("\nDelete 20"); 
    tree.deleteKey(20); 
    System.out.println("Inorder traversal of the modified tree"); 
    tree.inorder(); 

    System.out.println("\nDelete 30"); 
    tree.deleteKey(30); 
    System.out.println("Inorder traversal of the modified tree"); 
    tree.inorder(); 

    System.out.println("\nDelete 50"); 
    tree.deleteKey(50); 
    System.out.println("Inorder traversal of the modified tree"); 
    tree.inorder(); 
  } 
}
```